# Why my gradle get the exit code 137

Tags: java, android, gradle

Here is the log:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137

Comment: Try cleaning your project.